# How to display a multiplication table from inputted row and column in jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm a bit struggling on coding multiplication table using jquery, so i already have the code to display the multiplication table from the inputted row, the multiplication table that i need is to display it from inputting how many rows and columns.

Hoping for y'all could help me, big thanks.

```js
$( ".button" ).click(function() {
    var n = document.getElementById( "num" ).value; 
    var arr = [];
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        arr[i] = [];

    var sub = 1;
    var count = 1;
    i = 0;
    while (count <= n){   
        var loopcount = 1;
        while (loopcount <= n){
            arr[i].push(sub);
            sub += count;
            loopcount++;
        }
        count++;
        sub = count;
        i++;
    }
  
    var $table = $("<table></table>");
    var $row;
    arr.forEach(function(subArr){ 
        $row = $("<tr></tr>"); 
        subArr.forEach(function(el){ 
            $row.append('<td>' + el + '</td>');
        });
        $table.append($row);
    });
    $table.appendTo(document.body);
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
margin: 150px auto;
max-width: 800px;
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
}

form {
  padding: 4em 4em 2em;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

td {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  margin: 0 0 .5em;
  color: #000;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="button"] {
  display: block;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #848484;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

table {
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 5px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 24px;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <h1>multiplication table</h1>
    <form>
        <label for="num">Input number of rows</label>
        <input type="text" value="" id="num"/>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" class="button"/>
        <p id="answer"></p>
        <div id="myDiv"></div>
    </form>
        
</div> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your current code, you could add a second input to get the number of columns, get the value of that   entered variable  and in the second while loop `while (loopcount <= n){` use that instead of `n`

```js
$(".button").click(function() {
  var n = document.getElementById("num").value;
  var c = document.getElementById("cols").value;
  var arr = [];
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    arr[i] = [];
  var sub = 1;
  var count = 1;
  i = 0;
  while (count <= n) {
    var loopcount = 1;
    while (loopcount <= c) {
      arr[i].push(sub);
      sub += count;
      loopcount++;
    }
    count++;
    sub = count;
    i++;
  }

  var $table = $("<table></table>");
  var $row;
  arr.forEach(function(subArr) {
    $row = $("<tr></tr>");
    subArr.forEach(function(el) {
      $row.append('<td>' + el + '</td>');
    });
    $table.append($row);
  });
  $table.appendTo(document.body);

});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 150px auto;
  max-width: 800px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
}

form {
  padding: 4em 4em 2em;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

td {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  margin: 0 0 .5em;
  color: #000;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="button"] {
  display: block;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #848484;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label for="num">Input number of rows</label>
  <input type="text" value="" id="num" />
  <label for="num">Input number of columns</label>
  <input type="text" value="" id="cols" />
  <input type="button" value="Submit" class="button" />
  <p id="answer"></p>
  <div id="myDiv"></div>
</form>
```